# How do I extend <td> in Dart Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In Dart, I've been trying to create a polymer element that extends .

```dart
@CustomTag('deckname-td-item')
class DecknameTdItemElement extends TableCellElement with Polymer, Observable {
  @published String item;

  DecknameTdItemElement.created() : super.created();    

  void wordFileClicked(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    String deckName =  $['deckAnchor'].text;        
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('decknameclicked', detail: deckName)); 
  }
}
```

Corresponding html:

```html
<polymer-element name="deckname-td-item" extends="td">
<template>
  <style>
    a {
     font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  <a id='deckAnchor' href="#" on-click="{{wordFileClicked}}">{{item}}</a>
</template>
<script type="application/dart" src="deckname_td_item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Usage:

```html
<td is="deckname-td-item" item="{{wordFile}}" 
   on-decknameclicked="{{deckNameChanged1}}"></td>
```

Everything works fine in Dartium, and it compiles without any warnings, but when I run the output of the build, I get:

```
Uncaught Unsupported operation: extendsTag does not match base native class
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No answers yet? Perhaps post a message on this forum: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/web

Answer (score 1):

HtmlDocument.register(String tag, Type customElementClass, {String extendsTag}) doc says

The [nativeTagName] parameter is needed by platforms without native support

when subclassing a native type other than:

- HtmlElement
- SvgElement
- AnchorElement
- AudioElement
- ButtonElement
- CanvasElement
- DivElement
- ImageElement
- InputElement
- LIElement
- LabelElement
- MenuElement
- MeterElement
- OListElement
- OptionElement
- OutputElement
- ParagraphElement
- PreElement
- ProgressElement
- SelectElement
- SpanElement
- UListElement
- VideoElement

My guess is that polymer does provide this optional parameter

Answer (score 1):

```dart
@CustomTag('ext-td')
class extendedTd extends TableCellElement with Polymer, Observable {

  extendedTd.created() : super.created() {
    polymerCreated();
  }
}
```

I did this and mine worked properly.

Comment: Well I have a workaround for both of them. With "working properly" in this answer i just refer to the extended td, since that works perfectly fine.